# How to create a map out of two lists?

Tags: scala

I have two lists

```
val a = List(1,2,3)
val b = List(5,6,7)
```

I'd like to create a Map like:

```
val h = Map(1->5, 2->6, 3->7)
```

basically iterating thru both the lists and assigning key value pairs.

How to do it properly in Scala?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can `zip` the lists together into a list of tuples, then call `toMap`:

```
(a zip b) toMap
```

Note that if one list is longer than the other, it will be truncated.

---

Example:

```
val a = List(1, 2, 3)
val b = List(5, 6, 7)

scala> (a zip b) toMap
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 5, 2 -> 6, 3 -> 7)
```

With truncation:

```
val c = List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

scala> (a zip c) toMap
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c)

(c zip a) toMap
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3)
```

Comment: Hi @Michael Zajac, A follow up question on this, I am using this zip method, but when I print my Map the key value pairs are not in the same order as originally. I mean I am getting like Map ( b-> 2,  c->3, a -> 1). Is there a way I can maintain the order of the Map elements as my first List ? Thank you so much